# How to write if/else statement

Tags: if-statement, knockout.js, conditional-statements

I have to check if a variable equals a certain string e.g.

```
if (product_type == "simple") { ... }
```

How can I do this in knockout.js? I have read the [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), but not sure where to look.

**Attempt:**

```
<!-- ko if: is_product_type && product_type == "simple" -->
<div class="primary">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('foo')}" class="action edit">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
 <!-- ko else: -->
<div class="primary">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('bar')}" class="action edit">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

↑ does not work, it renders both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other alternative is to use the **ifnot** binding.  For more complex scenarios I would  generally move these types of decisions into the viewmodel

```
<!-- ko if: product_type == "simple" -->
<div class="primary">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('foo')}" class="action edit">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: product_type == "simple" -->
<div class="primary">
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('bar')}" class="action edit">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
This is a simple demo of how you can move some decisions out of the html and into the viewmodel

```js
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.option1 = ko.observable(false);
  self.option2 = ko.observable(true);
  self.option3 = ko.observable(true);
  self.option4 = ko.observable(true);
  self.showEditLink = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.option1() && self.option2() && self.option3() && self.option4();
  });

  self.configure_url = ko.observable('https://stackoverflow.com');
  

}



ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option1" /> Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option2" /> Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option3" /> Option 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option4" /> Option 4</label>
    
    <!-- ko if: showEditLink -->
    <br/>
    <div class="primary">
        <a data-bind="text: configure_url, attr: {href: configure_url}" class="action edit">
           
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

```js
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.option1 = ko.observable(false);
  self.option2 = ko.observable(true);
  self.option3 = ko.observable(true);
  self.option4 = ko.observable(true);
  self.showEditLink = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.option1() && self.option2() && self.option3() && self.option4();
  });

  self.configure_url = ko.observable('https://stackoverflow.com');
  self.product_type = ko.observable('foo');
  
  self.getTitle = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    switch (self.product_type()){
      case 'foo': return 'Product type: Foo';
      case 'bar': return 'Product type: Bar';
      default: return 'Unknown Product type';
    }
  
  });
}



ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    
    <label>Product Type: <input data-bind="textInput: product_type" /></label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option1" /> Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option2" /> Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option3" /> Option 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: option4" /> Option 4</label>
    
    <div class="primary" data-bind="if: showEditLink">
        <a data-bind="text: getTitle, attr: {href: configure_url, title: getTitle }" class="action edit">
            
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Im new to knockoutjs, can you show an example how to outsource it to a view model please?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like knockout.js does not even support `else`, so you have to create a dirty workaround:

```
<!-- ko if: product_type == "simple" -->
    <div class="primary">
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('foo')}" class="action edit">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: product_type != "simple" -->
    <div class="primary">
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('bar')}" class="action edit">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```